# Strange behavior with the hotkeys in VC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, hotkeys

I have a dialog written in VC++ as shown below:

---

Label1  Control1

---

Button1

---

If Control1 is disabled, using Label1's hotkey results in Button1's Click event. How could I avoid that? As Control1 is disabled shouldn't the hotkey for Label1 too?

Comment: When you say a label is that a CStatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a CStatic, have you tried disabling it at the same time as the control it's referencing?

Comment: +1 - definitely try disabling the label as well as the control

Comment: Disabling will work for sure. I wonder, what they achieved by propagating the hotkey to another control?